# How do you use scale in .css()?

Tags: jquery, css

In normal CSS, I would do this:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
```

How do I do this with the JQuery `.css()`?

I've tried this:

```
$("#element").css("webkit-transform","scale (1.25)");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:-

```
$('#element').css({
  '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(1.25)',
  '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(1.25)',
  '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(1.25)',
  '-o-transform'      : 'scale(1.25)',
  'transform'         : 'scale(1.25)'
});
```